# How to loop through all elements of certain class BEFORE executing a code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

Let's say i have a class "dog". I have 5 elements which all have the class "dog". I want to check if all the elements which have the class "dog" have a certain background-color. If they have i want to execute a certain code. I do **NOT** want to loop through each element and execute the code in between every iteration. What I want is to first check ALL the elements that do they have the certain background-color before executing a code.

I tried this:

```
function openBtn () {
  green = 'rgb(144, 238, 144)';

  if ($('.glassver').css('background-color') == green || $('.glasshor').css('background-color') == green || $('.glassxyz').css('background-color') == green) {
    $('#orderBtn').removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#orderBtn').css("background-color", "#3da669");
  } else {
    $('#orderBtn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#orderBtn').css("background-color", 'lightgray');
  }
}
```

Comment: Post the code that you attempted.

Comment: Yeah ofc, sry! There it is

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: And what is the issue with your code? What's not working? Error?

Comment: I am able to add div elements to the program with a button. Lets say I add 3 divs with the button. When the user gives some input to a form the divs change color to green. I want to check if all the 3 divs are changed to green before executing the removeAttr() part.

Answer (score 2):

Get all the div elements which have `dog` class and build an array from them.

Then use the `every` method of array to check your background color condition.
If it is true for all of them, execute your code

```js
const dogs = Array.from(document.querySelector('div.dog'));
if (dogs.every(d => d.style.backgroundColor === 'red')) {
  console.log('do some code');
}
```

```html
<div class="dog" style="background-color:red">DOG 1</div>
<div class="dog" style="background-color:red">DOG 2</div>
```

Comment: I don't know if it is because the program doesn't have the divs at the start, but the user has to add them via button.